# How System.out.println('teststring') prints the value on console? which native method is doing the actual job?

Tags: java

I was searching java source code that prints the `System.out.println()` parameter values on the console. I checked `PrintStream`, `FilterOutputStream` and `OutputStream` classes, none of them have complete implementation of the method nor any reference to native code.

How does the `System.out.println` value getting printed on the console, which native method is doing the actual job ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to drill down through the decorator-pattern wrappers. At the bottom you'll find `FileOutputStream`, specifically this method:

```
private native void writeBytes(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

Use this code to play with it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  nav(nav(System.out));
}

static Object nav(Object o) throws Exception {
  final Field[] fs = o.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
  for (Field f : fs) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    final Object r = f.get(o);
    System.out.println(r);
    return r;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: @ Marko, thanks for the reply. I think jvm is linking native java call to native code using JNI. But still i wonder, when exactly jvm is loading DLLfiles? can we extract native methods from DLL files?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final PrintStream out
```

The "standard" output stream. This stream is already open and ready to accept output data. Typically this stream corresponds to display output or another output destination specified by the host environment or user.
For simple stand-alone Java applications, a typical way to write a line of output data is:

```
System.out.println(data)
```

where:

```
void println(String x)
```

Prints a String and then terminates the line.